# Throw not generated when accessing mapping with invalid key

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, exceptions

I'm trying to implement the current contract:

```
contract Mortal {
    address owner;

    event Killed(address indexed from);

    function Mortal() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function kill() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) {
            Killed(owner);
            suicide(owner);
        }
    }
}

/// @title Voting with delegation.
contract Ballot is Mortal {
    struct Voter {
        uint weight;
        bool voted;
        address delegate;
        uint vote;
    }

    struct Proposal {
        bytes32 name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    address public chairperson;

    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;

    Proposal[] public proposals;

    event GivenRightToVote(address indexed chairperson, address indexed voter);

    event Created(bytes32[] proposalNames);
    event Voted(address indexed voter, uint proposal);
    event Delegated(address indexed from, address indexed to);

    function Ballot(bytes32[] proposalNames) {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;
        for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
            proposals.push(Proposal({
                name: proposalNames[i],
                voteCount: 0
            }));
        }
        Created(proposalNames);
    }

    function giveRightToVote(address voter) {
        if (msg.sender != chairperson || voters[voter].voted) throw;
        voters[voter].weight = 1;
        GivenRightToVote(chairperson, voter);
    }

    function delegate(address to) {
        Voter sender = voters[msg.sender];
        if (sender.voted) throw;

        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0) &&
               voters[to].delegate != msg.sender)
            to = voters[to].delegate;

        if (to == msg.sender)
            throw;

        sender.voted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;

        Voter delegate = voters[to];
        if (delegate.voted) {
            proposals[delegate.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
        } else {
            delegate.weight += sender.weight;
        }

        Delegated(msg.sender, to);
    }

    function vote(uint proposal) {
        Voter sender = voters[msg.sender];
        if (!sender || sender.voted) throw;

        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = proposal;

        proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
        Voted(msg.sender, proposal);
    }

    /// @dev Computes the winning proposal taking all
    /// previous votes into account.
    function winningProposal() constant
        returns (uint winningProposal) {
        uint winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
            if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
                winningProposal = p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to deploy it and it seems to be working fine in most cases.

I'm watching votes with this callback:

```
var votedEvt = ballot.Voted({}, '', function(e, result) {
    if (!e) {
        console.log('Voter ' + result.args.voter + ' voted on proposal #' + result.args.proposal);
    } else {
        console.err(e);
    }
})
```

The problem is when I try to vote with an account that hasn't been given the right to. My watcher is still triggered and shows me:

```
> Voter 0xbfa3593... voted on proposal #1
```

The docs say that this line

```
Voter sender = voters[msg.sender];
```

should itself throw if there is no `msg.sender` key on `voters` mapping, but this is not what I'm getting.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In soldidity mappings exist as if all keys were present with their values set to `0x0`.  For structs this means that all of the fields will be in their `0x0` state.

Since `voters` is a mapping, you can access any key and it will return the `Voter` struct that corresponds to that key.  Only arrays throw when you access unset indices.

Comment: So, is there any way in which I can verify if an address is not a key for a mapping?

Comment: All addresses are part of a mapping, but they may virtually map to zero. If you need a list of "voters", you'll need to store them as a flat array too to act as indices into your map. Solidity doesn't support retrieving mapping keys (since 1: keys are hashed and not maintained themselves and 2: if you don't need iteration, it's costs that can be removed).

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos you cannot query in a generic way whether a key is present in a mapping.  You will either have to check that the returned value is non-zero or use a separate storage mechanism to track the presence of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Piper's answer, for completeness the code in the [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#voting) is:

```
    Voter sender = voters[msg.sender];
    if (sender.voted)
        throw;
```

Per @Piper's answer, `voters[msg.sender]` and `sender.voted` will never cause an exception, because firstly `voters` is a mapping and secondly `sender` is a `struct`.  (And `msg` always has a `sender`.)

So in this code, a `throw` only happens when `sender.voted` is `true`.